# Python: How to get the Index of a string

Tags: python, string, indexing

How can I write a function that returns the index of a single character in a string without using the index method a.k.a  `string.index('some random character')`?

Comment: Why can't you use that method?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

Comment: jhocking -- its specified in the instructions of my hw set not use that method

Mr E -- thank you for the link, unfortunately its all greek to me =/

Comment: Thank you everybody, the answers you all gave are all valid
Once again, Thank you very much!

Comment: Mr E gave you the link because you wrote "function that returns the index of a string" whereas you meant "function that returns the index of a *char*". The first is a much more comple problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a school task?

```
def ind(the_string, the_char):
   i = 0
   for a_char in the_string:
       if a_char == the_char: return i
       i += 1
   return -1
```

Comment: yes its for a hw set, and thank you very much Cek this did the trick!

Comment: the enumerate from lecodesportif's answer saves you the two lines of code, and it's nice `for i, a_char in enumerate(the_string)`

Answer (score 3):

Another variant that works with multiple occurrences of char in string.

```
def idx(string, char):
  for key, x in enumerate(string):
    if x == char:
      print key
```

Answer (score 0):

index() is the same thing as find() except for the error when the string isn't found.